# Importing libs does not import files only package folder

Tags: angularjs, dart

Hello I'm new to Dart and have a background in angularjs and js and learned dart with dartlang screencasts. So when I first tried to work with dart I couldn't reproduce a simple tutorial from the angulardart website, here are my files (notice the empty package folders besides shadow_dom):
[image: pubspec.yaml]

And here is my index file (notice the paths not found on the dart.)

[image: index.html]

And this is my main dart file.
[image: index.dart]

My dartium and dart sdk are properly installed, what could it possibly be?

Comment: I recently had this problem, your pub cache has probably become a bit messed up, use the command [`pub cache repair`](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/IHKRAdX1W-w)

Comment: you can add it to you PATH so you can run it from anywhere, or like I do, just open a command terminal in the folder where the pub.bat script lives in your dart installation and run it directly from there. for me that is in here `C:\Program Files\dart\dart-sdk\bin`

Comment: It worked, can you do an answer so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be the result of the pub cache becoming *confused*, run `pub cache repair` to resolve the issue.